# Adding a .tar.bz package to my local repository?

Tags: apt

I downloaded a software package in a .tar.bz file.

I understand that I can install such packages through `make install`, but then there's no easy way to uninstall. Is there a way that I can add this package to my local repository, so that I can install/uninstall it through `apt-get`?

Comment: checkinstall does this, see duplicate

Comment: "but then there's no easy way to uninstall". explain? Most of them just require you to `rm` the directory you unpacked. How hard is that?

Comment: @Rinzwind After unpacking, you still need to install the package, which may copy files to many directories.

Comment: The tar.bz files I have here all have a complete directory structure and are installed to the dir you install it into (and here that means /opt/). I have 19 of those here and all 19 are just "unpack and execute".

Comment: @Rinzwind you're lucky enough to be using compiled binaries or you are knowledgeable enough to configure the source with `--prefix=/opt`.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton Indeed, that solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Some tar.bz files don't actually need "make install". They are already compiled for your version of Ubuntu.  To delete these, just delete the folder that you extracted them into. e.g. fritzing-0.9.0b.linux.AMD64.tar_1.bz2
- If you use "make install" you can just delete the folders that it creates
- If you use "sudo make install" files can be placed all over your system, so you'll have to look in the make file and see what it did and remove everything. A lot more complicated!